# How to set EAX to inputted value before calling a procedure

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode:DWORD
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
prompt BYTE "Please enter the lower bound: ", 0
prompt2 BYTE "Please enter the upper bound: ", 0
lowerbound SDWORD ?
count DWORD ?


.code
main PROC

    mov ecx, 3

L1:
    mov count, ecx  
    mov ecx, 30 
    mov edx, OFFSET prompt
    call WriteString
    call ReadInt
    mov lowerbound, eax

    mov edx, OFFSET prompt2
    call WriteString
    call ReadInt
    mov ebx, lowerbound

L2:
    call BetterRandomRange
    call WriteInt
    call crlf
    loop L2
    
    mov ecx, count
    loop L1
    exit
    INVOKE ExitProcess,0
main ENDP

BetterRandomRange PROC ;loop 3 times

sub eax, ebx
call RandomRange
add eax, ebx            this keeps in within range but causes a division by zero error
;sub eax, ebx        no error but slightly out of range for the 30 iterations
ret

BetterRandomRange ENDP

END main
```

I'm trying to complete the problem of generating an integer between M and N-1 based on user input, where M is in EBX (lower bound) and N is in EAX (upper bound) and the number is returned in EAX.

I've somewhat located the error because the upper bound is not stored in EAX before calling BetterRandomRange. However, I'm unsure on how to fix this because EAX and EBX have the correct bound values in the first iteration. I'm new to assembly and still learning it so it's a bit confusing for me. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: ReadInt will overwrite EAX, so you'd need to preserve it before calling BetterRandomRange. EAX is a volatile register and can be accessed/modified at any point

Comment: @Irelia **Read**Int is not the problem. On the first iteration of the L2 loop, the correct value in EAX is passed on to *BetterRandomRange*. It's the output of *BetterRandomRange* and the subsequent use of **Write**Int and *crlf* that clobbers EAX.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `BetterRandomRange` the first time, it will change the value in `eax`.  In addition `WriteInt` and `crlf` will likely change it too as `eax` is not preserved across functions.  So in the second iteration, `eax` contains whatever `crlf` left there rather than the upperbound.

What you need to do is to store the upperbound (perhaps a static var as you do with `lowerbound`) and reload it before calling `BetterRandomRange each time in the loop.

Comment: Irvine32 uses its own calling convention where every register is call-preserved, except the return value if there is any. (And integer inputs if any are in EAX or EDX or something.)  So `WriteInt` and `crlf` actually don't modify EAX.

Answer (score 0):

First input your *upperbound* and put that in a variable:

```
mov  edx, OFFSET prompt2
call WriteString
call ReadInt            ; -> EAX
mov  upperbound, eax
```

Then input your *lowerbound* and put that in EBX:

```
mov  edx, OFFSET prompt
call WriteString
call ReadInt            ; -> EAX
mov  ebx, eax           ; lowerbound
```

Code in the *L2* loop will not clobber the EBX register, but the EAX register gets modified by *BetterRandomRange*. So reload the *upperbound* from its variable:

```
L2:
    mov  eax, upperbound                    <<<< new
    call BetterRandomRange  ; -> EAX
    call WriteInt
    call crlf
    loop L2
```

> ```
> BetterRandomRange PROC ;loop 3 times
> ```

Doesn't the *L2* loop run 30 times? It's the *L1* loop that runs 3 times.

---

The quickest fix for your present code would preserve the value from EAX on the stack:

```
L2:
    push eax                                <<<< new
    call BetterRandomRange  ; -> EAX
    call WriteInt
    call crlf
    pop  eax                                <<<< new
    loop L2
```

> ```
> L2:
> ```

This is **not** an instruction. *L2* just corresponds to the address in memory where the `push eax` instruction (that follows) is located. This is the top of the loop. The first time ECX=30

> ```
>    push eax
> ```

The stackpointer ESP gets subtracted by 4, and the EAX register gets written at `[esp]`. (ESP points at the preserved EAX).

> ```
>    call BetterRandomRange  ; -> EAX
> ```

The stackpointer ESP gets subtracted by 4, and the return address gets written at `[esp]`. Next the instruction pointer EIP moves to the *BetterRandomRange* procedure where the code calculates a new value for EAX and then returns here. In order to return, the instruction pointer EIP is loaded from `[esp]` and then the stackpointer gets raised by 4. (ESP again points at the preserved EAX).

> ```
>    call WriteInt
> ```

The stackpointer ESP gets subtracted by 4, and the return address gets written at `[esp]`. Next the instruction pointer EIP moves to the *WriteInt* procedure where the code writes the value in EAX to the screen and then returns here. It is fine for *WriteInt* to clobber the EAX register in the process. In order to return, the instruction pointer EIP is loaded from `[esp]` and then the stackpointer gets raised by 4. (ESP again points at the preserved EAX).

> ```
>    call crlf
> ```

The stackpointer ESP gets subtracted by 4, and the return address gets written at `[esp]`. Next the instruction pointer EIP moves to the *crlf* procedure where the code writes a newline to the screen and then returns here. It is fine for *crlf* to clobber the EAX register in the process. In order to return, the instruction pointer EIP is loaded from `[esp]` and then the stackpointer gets raised by 4. (ESP again points at the preserved EAX).

> ```
>    pop  eax
> ```

The EAX register is loaded from `[esp]` and then the stackpointer gets raised by 4. EAX is now restored to the *upperbound* value.

> ```
>    loop L2
> ```

The ECX register gets decremented and if it is non-zero the branch is taken. The execution then continues at the top of the loop. If ECX was decremented to zero, the execution would fall through in the following lines, thereby ending the loop.

### Don't feel compelled to use the `loop` instruction for your loops

Your *L1* loop currently is:

> ```
>     mov ecx, 3
> L1:
>     mov count, ecx
>     mov  ecx, 30
>
>     ...
>
>     mov ecx, count
>     loop L1
> ```

You can avoid the deprecated (because it is slow) `loop` instruction in several ways:

```
  mov  count, 3
L1:
  mov  ecx, 30    
  ...

  dec  count
  jnz  L1
```

Another way is:

```
  mov  ecx, 3
L1:
  push ecx
  mov  ecx, 30

  ...

  pop  ecx
  dec  ecx
  jnz  L1
```

You can avoid `loop` in the *L2* loop in a similar manner.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed help! My errors make a lot more sense now. I'm sorry for this dumb question but I understand how push and pop work in a high level sense where push stores values while pop removes a value from the stack, but could I get a walkthrough with what's happening in L2?

Comment: @clq Did the 'walkthrough' that I added to my answer help you in any way? I see you have moved on to asking another question leaving this one open.